# Downloading data file from website to RStudio in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: rstudio

How can I download a data file from a website into RStudio using ubuntu 17.10?

I am using the command below, but I get an error:

```
unexpected / and unexpected "
cpd <- read.csv(url(“https://pub.data.gov.bc.ca/datasets/176284/BC_Liquor_Store_Product_Price_list.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD”))
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace the [smart quotes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-curly-quotes-to-straight-quotes-and-vice-versa-017963a0-bc5f-486b-9c9d-0ec511a8fb8f)

```
cpd <- read.csv(url(“https://pub.data.gov.bc.ca/datasets/176284/BC_Liquor_Store_Product_Price_list.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD”))
```

with regular ASCII double quotes:

```
cpd <- read.csv(url("https://pub.data.gov.bc.ca/datasets/176284/BC_Liquor_Store_Product_Price_list.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"))
```

Comment: Does it work as well for Ubuntu 17.04?